# Using "<<<" with subprocess module

Tags: bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I encounter a problem using subprocess module in python 2.7.
The problem is when i try to used <<< in my command.

Here is an simplified example :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

command="cat <<< 'hi there'"
print subprocess.check_output(command.split(" "))
```

And the results :

```
cat: '<<<': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
cat: "'hi": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
cat: "there'": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print subprocess.check_output(command.split(" "))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cat', '<<<', "'hi", "there'"]' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I'm confused about this results. Why is subprocess having problem when i try to use the <<< ? All my bash commands works except when i use "<<<" :/

Answer (score 0):

The `<<<` operator is a bash construct. You are not using bash in the command, so it won't work. Try adding `shell=True`.

Also, if you split your command in the spaces, you get quite weird parameters (check the error message). If the string has to be interpreted by bash, don't mess with it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

command="cat <<< 'hi there'"
print subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

Comment: In fact, <<< is for bash, so to solved my problem i need to use shell=True and executable="/bin/bash" ! And ti works.

Comment: I updated the answer with the `executable` detail. If that answered your question... accept it! :-)